# How to use mutators in laravel mass update?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, updates

I am currently updating multiple rows in my database by doing  the following:

I take an array in a post and loop through it, each member is an array of `fieldname=>value` and I am doing an update on each one. the problem is that the mutators I have set up do not get run when I update this way. is there another way to update that is efficient and will call the mutators?

code:

```
foreach ($post['row'] as $row) {
     Instances::where('id', $row['id'])->update($row);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably will be able to use your mutators by doing something like:

```
foreach ($post['row'] as $row) 
{
     $data = Instances::where('id', $row['id'])->first();

     foreach($row as $key => $value)
     {
        $data->$key = $value; // which is the same as $data->setAttribute($key, $value);
     }

     $data->save();
}
```

Can't you just override the update method?

```
class BaseModel extends Eloquent {

    public function update($array)
    {
        parent::update($this->trimAll($array));
    }

    public function trimAll($data)
    {
        /// trim them here
    }

}
```

And you can keep using:

```
Instances::where('id', $row['id'])->update($row);
```

Comment: would there be any different in doing that versus:
    `foreach($row as $key => $value)
     {
        $data->$key=$value;
     }`

Comment: Oh! No, that's the same.

Comment: I was hoping to find a way around this type of solution, but I guess if that's the only way to update and get mutator functionality I will have to do it that way.

Comment: Yeah, when Laravel uses QueryBuilder (insert) it just glues the query items, add the bindings and send to your database server. What you could do is to create a trigger in your database server to trim those fields before saving.

Comment: Or you could create a BaseModel, override the insert method and trim the values in the array before execution of the real insert.

Comment: Yea, I am only having trouble with the update now...if you use `create()` it will actually call the mutator, just an FYI.

Comment: that looks like it will work for sure, would I still call the update function in the same way?

Comment: You probably will, I'm hoping that in this case it will call Eloquent update and not QueryBuilder, but it probably will.